# How to pass some property on startup class and initialize it on controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1, kestrel-http-server

I have a .net core 3.1 background application where i am spanning kestrel server as per implementation.
What i need is to initialize some property (let's say int channel id) when it is configured at startup

Startup

```
internal class Startup
{
    internal static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(MyConfigurations _objSettings)
    {
    
        //_objSettings.channelId need to be assigned to CallBackController channelID
        return Host
            .CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => 
                webBuilder.UseUrls(_objSettings.CallbackLocalListener)
            )
            .UseStartup<Startup>());
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers(options => options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true);
        services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseForwardedHeaders();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

Controller

```
[Produces("application/json")]
public class CallBackController : ControllerBase
{          
    int channelId = 0;//this need to be initializes 

    public IActionResult Receive()
    {
        IActionResult result = null;
       
        return result;
    }
}
```

I needed this as same class multiple instances will be starting kestrel instance on other ports listening different traffic. At the time of request receive i need that channel Id to initialize something

Comment: Where is your program.cs? cant you just use some arbitrary value?

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro arbitrary value for what? My question is regarding passing any parameter to startup class then initialize that parameter in my controller instance

Comment: Exactly.  You can pass any value to your controllers using dependency injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an type to store the  desired options

```
public class ChannelOptions {
    public int ChannelId { get; set; }
}
```

and configure that in Startup using the convivence members

```
internal static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(MyConfigurations _objSettings) {        
    return Host
        .CreateDefaultBuilder()
        .ConfigureServices(services => 
            services.AddSingleton(
                new ChannelOptions {
                    ChannelId = _objSettings.channelID
                }
            )
        )
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => 
            webBuilder.UseUrls(_objSettings.CallbackLocalListener)
        )
        .UseStartup<Startup>());
}
```

and finally, explicitly inject the options into the controller as a dependency

```
[Produces("application/json")]
public class CallBackController : ControllerBase {

    private readonly int channelId = 0;

    public CallBackController(ChannelOptions options) {
        channelId = options?.ChannelId ?? 0;
    }

    public IActionResult Receive() {
        IActionResult result = null;
       
        return result;
    }
    
    //...
}
```

Comment: I have seen similar solution but my concern is about AddSingleton. Does it effect any thing about my controller normal request response capability?

Comment: @KamranShahid No. the container will inject that dependency into the controller when resolving it for requests.